# Implement post status update as frontend news announcement

Tags: custom-post-types, post-status

Is there a way to implement a function to print status update on the home page.

eg.

```
2016/04/17, there are 2 articles posted in category ABC
2016/04/17, there are 3 articles posted in category DEF
2016/04/15, there are 5 articles posted in category XYZ
```

I would like to keep 7 days of rolling record as news update to show on the home page or sidebar.

The articles are custom post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help:

```php
function wpse_display_post_counts_by_categories() {

    $categories = get_categories();
    $container = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $args = [
            'post_type'      => 'post', // Change to your post type.
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'category'       => $category->term_id,
            'orderby'        => 'post_date',
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ];
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if ( count($posts) ) { // Indexing by post date of the latest post in the category.
            $container[strtotime($posts[0]->post_date)] = [
                'id'     => $category->term_id,
                'name'   => $category->name,
                'counts' => count($posts)
            ];
        }
    }

    krsort($container); // Sort by key(post date), from high to low to get latest updated categories.

    $values = array_slice($container, 0, 3, true); // Get only 3 latest updated categories.

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $output = sprintf( __('%s, there are %d articles posted in category <a href="%s">%s</a>', 'text-domain'), date_i18n('Y/m/d', $key), $value['counts'], esc_url( get_term_link($value['id'], 'category') ), $value['name']);
        echo '<p>' . $output . '</p>'; // Whatever markup you need.
    }

}
```

IMHO: Currently, I don't figure out a more efficient way to do this. I don't know how you handle the `$categories` when there are too many to loop through. I don't recommend to do this. It's too much just for printing out some statuses.

Comment: This prints all my categories and the number of posts in each category. For example, I only need to print the news update for the past 3 updating dates as shown in the example.  How do I specify that?  It does get the latest date of update for each category, but the number of posts is the total posts without matching the dates. Another thing, can I also extract the link to the category and make it clickable in `$output`?

Comment: My idea for improvement is to get the 'counts' from the array for all posts where the date matches $posts[0] so that it counts the total for most recent post.  How do I implement this?  Yet this does not solve the problem of shows past 3 updating dates, but only latest update for each category.  Any other suggestion?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it work for you!

Comment: Thank you for working on the code.  The category url is printed correctly.  However, it still shows all the post counts in each category.  I probably didn't explain it clearly.  For example, yesterday I made 5 posts in `cat A`, today I made 3 posts in `cat B`, where in total, `cat A has 10 posts` and `cat B has 10 posts`.  The status update I would like to show on the front end is.  `Today, 5 new articles added to Cat A` and `Yesterday, 3 new articles added to Cat B`.

Comment: I would like to be able to specify, for example, 7 days of article publishing update to be shown on the frontend. The dates may be duplicated as sometimes I might have multiple articles published on different categories on the same date. Currently, the script is printing the total number of posts in each category, and showing the last article publishing date.  Do you think there's an efficient way of doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Another quick qestion, where do I place the `function()`?  Currently I'm taking the content of the `function()` and put a directly on the `index.php` template to test.  If I put it in `functions.php`, it doesn't do anything when I call it directly via `display_post_counts_by_categories();` in my `index.php`

Comment: 1. You must have a method to track the posts counts for a category each day. A custom post type, maybe.
2. You should put the function inside functions.php and call it from anywhere you want. Make sure to change the `post_type` and prefix the function properly.

Comment: I'll try to improve upon your code to fit my need.  Since everything will be cached, so I assume the database query won't be too big of an issue as I only have 4~5 categories.  Basically, the idea is to read the content of every category into an array, and then process it with calculated summary.  Do you know if there's a way to count unique index in an array?  For example, count the number of occurrence where the date index is the same.

Comment: I'm trying to move your code to `functions.php`, but it doesn't work.  In the process of debugging, I placed a `return $args; `, and array with argument content was return.  But when I placed a `return get_posts($args);`, an empty array was returned.  It seems that `get_posts($args)` is not working in `functions.php`.  Any idea  why this only works in the template file, but not in `functions.php`?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the function exactly? How did you call the function?

Comment: Yes, I copied and use the exact same function. It can return value of `$category->term_id`, `$args`, and `$categories`, only `return get_posts($args)` is giving me null array in `functions.php`.  I've tried to replaced `get_posts()` with `new WP_Query($args)` with some adjustment to the `$args`, and it works.  I'm still working on processing and array and using the `date` as unique array key after the count.